# Lambda-Expression: Check string for equality

Tags: vb.net

I want to check a string within a Lambda-Expression for equality, but it seems to be, that I only can use the function ".Contains". How I have to modify the following piece of code for checking a string for equality, if I want to check the "DESIGNATOR" for e.g. "TestEquipment"?

```vb
Dim removeIN As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Data.DataRow)()
removeIN = dtEinbau.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(r) CBool(r("DESIGNATOR").ToString.Contains("TestEquipment")) = True).ToList()
```

Comment: `.Where(Function(r) r("DESIGNATOR").ToString().Equals("TestEquipment")).ToList()`

Comment: Misread the question......you can also use ````String.Compare("TestEquipment", r("DESIGNATOR"), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = 0````

Comment: What do you mean by "I can only use the function `Contains`"?  What else did you try and what went wrong when you tried it?  I would expect you to be able to use the `=` operator or the `Equals` function.

Comment: As Craig wrote, `Dim removeIN = dtEinbau.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(r) r("DESIGNATOR").ToString() = "TestEquipment").ToList()` will work.